# How to get value from customer's Phone field in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want to create a field for phone in shopify registration form. So that i have written the following code at register.liquid:

```
 <label for="phone" class="label--hidden">Phone Number</label>   
 <input type="text" value="" name="customer[phone]" id="phone" class="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
```

But when i fetched all the customer data by shopify api , phone field is null for all the customers. I checked the documentation and didn't find helpful anything about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `note` field:

```
<input type="text" name="customer[note][Phone]" placeholder="Phone"/>
```

There's no way to save it directly into the customer's `phone` field using the registration form.

Comment: is this the final solution?

Comment: it works with the "phone" note, I expected the phone field to be populated

Comment: No, unfortunately, that still isn't doable

Comment: on shopify admin there is an option to edit the customer and add a phone directly on the customer. so it must be an option to save the phone number somehow. perhaps needed special phone number pattern such as for exam. +60 026-261-3547

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label>{{ customer.phone }}</label>
 <input type="text" name="[Phone]" value="{{ customer.phone }}">
```